# Flex 4 Changing Default Font

Tags: apache-flex, fonts, flex4

How do I install multiple fonts for both bold and normal, I am trying to change the default font.

```
<fx:Style>
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
    @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
    @namespace assets "assets.*";
    @namespace comp "comp.*";

    @font-face {
        font-family: localVerdana;
        src: url("assets/verdana.ttf");
        src: url("assets/verdanab.ttf");
    }

    s|Label {
        font-family: localVerdana;
    }

    s|TextInput {
        font-family: localVerdana;
    }

    s|TextArea {
        font-family: localVerdana;
    }

</fx:Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have one @font-face declaration for each style, weight of font you use

```
@font-face
{
    src:                    url("assets/verdana.ttf");
    font-family:            localVerdana;
    font-style:             normal;
    font-weight:            normal;
    embed-as-cff:           true;
    advanced-anti-aliasing: true;

}

@font-face
{
    src:                    url("assets/verdanab.ttf");
    font-family:            localVerdana;
    font-style:             normal;
    font-weight:            bold;
    embed-as-cff:           true;
    advanced-anti-aliasing: true;

}
```